# GET/POST Request from Jelastic environment to another: connection refused

Tags: jelastic

I'm trying to make GET/POST requests from one Jelastic environment to another. Both are running Node/Express. I tried with env name (which works from my local machine) and internal IP address, but I always get a connection refused error:

> FetchError: request to https://10.101.19.55/converter failed,
> reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.101.19.55:443

Any hint on how to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention how your application is deployed (on what node type), but most likely it isn't listening on port 443; that only works remotely (if it does) because of proxying by the Shared Load Balancer of the Jelastic platform.

If you want to connect internally (between Jelastic nodes within the same platform), your requests do not pass via the Shared Load Balancer so cannot take advantage of that proxying.

In other words, you need to:

- connect directly to the port you application actually runs on, such as https://10.101.19.55:5000/converter (if your application is running/listening on port 5000)
- ensure that your firewall rules permit access from where you're connecting from

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I was able to solve it by using the internal port as you suggested (and adding firewall inbound rule to allow access to the port from source LAN). additionally, as my express server is running without SSL, I had to use http instead of https. for this to work in node-fetch, I used `const http = require('http');
const httpAgent = new http.Agent();`
and then agent: httpAgent in the fetch request.